# Adding PHP to a static site. Not sure if my workflow is right

Tags: php, mysql, html

Let's try to explain the title of my question to be the more concise I can: I'm basically designing a static HTML website from scratch. Nothing to worry about here.

The point is that I'm trying to include some links that will retrieve some items (a product inventory) from a database (and therefore the site won't be so 'static' anymore), as there're > 300 products and creating an html for each one is not feasible.

After googling and reading several sites for days, the "easiest" solution I came up with is to use PHP and MySQL. Again, nothing to worry about. Just took my time for reading documentation and move along.

My question is more related about the correct workflow for integrating both worlds. Let's see my idea in code:

This is one schematic example of the page where you can browse some products (e.g: product.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Site - These are our products</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Site goes here-->
    <a href="product_search_by_name.php">Search by name</a>
    <a href="product_search_by_color.php">Search by color</a>
    <!--rest of site goes here-->
</body>

</html>
```

Where the links

```
product_search_by_name.php
product_search_by_color.php
```

are actually a modified clone of the same page (product.html). This is, **keeping same html code**, **plus the .php code embedded into it**, as I want to have the DB results displayed into a **div** on that same page, keeping exactly same layout.

So, am I doing this right if I want to maintain the appearance of the whole website? I'm absolutely wrong from the base and should start again? Should I give up and work selling frappuchinos on a Star*ucks?

As a sample of the idea I want to achieve is the following: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp (when you click on the left menu bar, the center zone updates with the content). By the way, are they using AJAX on that website to update just the center zone, or I'm misunderstanding what is AJAX for?

I'm sure I'm missing something but I'm too confused to separate the sheep from the goats, so I'd thank a lot any tips you can give to me (and additional documentation on the internets to read as well).

Comment: That just creates a hyperlink to a php page, it doesn't embed/include the result of php file into the html.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com its a good tutorial site like stackoverflow.

Comment: @cillosis They both useful, just work in different ways.

Comment: Note: "<title>My Site - These are our products</title>" is the text that appears on the window bar, you may want to add "<h1>My Site - These are our products</h1>" the same text as text in your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways to merge or migrate from static HTML to dynamic HTML (PHP, PERL, whatever).

(1) One is to have most of the contest as HTML, and the stuff like inventory as dynamic.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Site - These are our products</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Site - These are our products</h1>

  <?php
  // php code to retrieve links
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

(2) To have a full PHP site.

```
<?php
echo "<html>" . "\n";
echo "<head>";
echo "My Site - These are our products"
echo "</head>";


echo "<body>" . "\n";
  // php code to retrieve links
echo "</body>" . "\n";

echo "</html>" . "\n";
?>
```

Many developers start by merging both HTML & PHP.

I suggest to learn how to do a very simple but full php site, connect to a database, retrieve some records with a S.Q.L. query, display them as read-only text or links, and later you may change to the other HTML plus PHP way of doing things.

There are several editors and tools to help develop in PHP, specially by looking for a PHP function, or just highlight HTML tags. Scintilla (Linux) or Notepad++ in windowze, its a very simple yet useful tool.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your time, umlcat. Right now I have two active .php files, which are responsible to give out the results from the DB. One without any layout (plain, just to see the results and debug) and another one with the website's layout. So as far as I understand the better option is to convert the site to full PHP (not a big deal it's a tiny website by now). I've read somewhere you can include an HTML layout into the PHP, saving lots of 'echo' commands. I'll try that as well. I'm using Aptana Studio for the editing (perhaps much overkill for my needs), so that'll be fair! Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want it to make it using Ajax ...

You might want to do the following.

1. Create the two files as you said, those are not to be included in the HTML file.
2. Create a JavaScript function to call the files, You can use jQuery api, to link to php. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
3. Link the click of the button inquired to call the JavaScript function, and add html you get from php to the tag you want.

Comment: Thanks Aladdin. If possible, I want to avoid using AJAX keeping things simple. I will PHP-ize the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a index.php page and put down your html code in it. It looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
<!--- links goes here -->
<a href="product_search_by_name.php">Search Products</a>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are retrieving products from a database and if you want to create multiple links for the products create a function in your function.php which pulls all the product name from the database. Now add this function into your index.php

```
index.php

<?php include ('functions.php')?>
<html>
<body>
<h3>Product List</h3>
<a href="<?productlist()?>">product name</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Always embed html in php file. Do not embed php in html file. File should have .php extension.

Comment: Thank you for your time as well! I think I'll follow ulmcat's suggestions and rebuild the entire site to make it full PHP. Not a big deal, as by now the site is quite tiny. I take note of your function to retrieve the links as well.